# RuntimeError: Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was trying to render text with LaTeX in Matplotlib.
There is a demo provided by Matplotlib at https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/tex_demo.html.

However, when I ran this demo, I got this error saying "RuntimeError: Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found", but I'm sure I have installed Miktex and Ghostscript required by Matlibplot.

Anyone knows how should I solve it?
Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


t = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 100)
s = np.cos(4 * np.pi * t) + 2

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4), tight_layout=True)
ax.plot(t, s)

ax.set_xlabel(r'\textbf{time (s)}')
ax.set_ylabel('\\textit{Velocity (\N{DEGREE SIGN}/sec)}', fontsize=16)
ax.set_title(r'\TeX\ is Number $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty'
             r'\frac{-e^{i\pi}}{2^n}$!', fontsize=16, color='r')
plt.show()
```

Here is the error trace back:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 304, in _run_checked_subprocess
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\subprocess.py", line 403, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The System Cannot Find the File Specified
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 746, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py", line 338, in idle_draw
    self.draw()
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 9, in draw
    super(FigureCanvasTkAgg, self).draw()
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 388, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 38, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1702, in draw
    **self._tight_parameters)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 2476, in tight_layout
    pad=pad, h_pad=h_pad, w_pad=w_pad, rect=rect)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\tight_layout.py", line 362, in get_tight_layout_figure
    pad=pad, h_pad=h_pad, w_pad=w_pad)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\tight_layout.py", line 111, in auto_adjust_subplotpars
    tight_bbox_raw = union([ax.get_tightbbox(renderer) for ax in subplots
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\tight_layout.py", line 112, in <listcomp>
    if ax.get_visible()])
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 4355, in get_tightbbox
    bb_xaxis = self.xaxis.get_tightbbox(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1164, in get_tightbbox
    self._update_label_position(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 2014, in _update_label_position
    bboxes, bboxes2 = self._get_tick_boxes_siblings(renderer=renderer)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1999, in _get_tick_boxes_siblings
    tlb, tlb2 = axx.xaxis._get_tick_bboxes(ticks_to_draw, renderer)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1150, in _get_tick_bboxes
    for tick in ticks if tick.label1.get_visible()],
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1150, in <listcomp>
    for tick in ticks if tick.label1.get_visible()],
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 890, in get_window_extent
    bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 291, in _get_layout
    ismath="TeX" if self.get_usetex() else False)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 201, in get_text_width_height_descent
    s, fontsize, renderer=self)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 448, in get_text_width_height_descent
    dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 338, in make_dvi
    texfile], tex)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 308, in _run_checked_subprocess
    'found'.format(command[0])) from exc
RuntimeError: Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 304, in _run_checked_subprocess
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\subprocess.py", line 403, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The System Cannot Find the File Specified
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py", line 259, in resize
    self.draw()
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 9, in draw
    super(FigureCanvasTkAgg, self).draw()
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 388, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 38, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1702, in draw
    **self._tight_parameters)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 2476, in tight_layout
    pad=pad, h_pad=h_pad, w_pad=w_pad, rect=rect)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\tight_layout.py", line 362, in get_tight_layout_figure
    pad=pad, h_pad=h_pad, w_pad=w_pad)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\tight_layout.py", line 111, in auto_adjust_subplotpars
    tight_bbox_raw = union([ax.get_tightbbox(renderer) for ax in subplots
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\tight_layout.py", line 112, in <listcomp>
    if ax.get_visible()])
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 4355, in get_tightbbox
    bb_xaxis = self.xaxis.get_tightbbox(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1164, in get_tightbbox
    self._update_label_position(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 2014, in _update_label_position
    bboxes, bboxes2 = self._get_tick_boxes_siblings(renderer=renderer)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1999, in _get_tick_boxes_siblings
    tlb, tlb2 = axx.xaxis._get_tick_bboxes(ticks_to_draw, renderer)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1150, in _get_tick_bboxes
    for tick in ticks if tick.label1.get_visible()],
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1150, in <listcomp>
    for tick in ticks if tick.label1.get_visible()],
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 890, in get_window_extent
    bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 291, in _get_layout
    ismath="TeX" if self.get_usetex() else False)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 201, in get_text_width_height_descent
    s, fontsize, renderer=self)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 448, in get_text_width_height_descent
    dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 338, in make_dvi
    texfile], tex)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 308, in _run_checked_subprocess
    'found'.format(command[0])) from exc
RuntimeError: Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 304, in _run_checked_subprocess
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\subprocess.py", line 403, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The System Cannot Find the File Specified

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 746, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py", line 338, in idle_draw
    self.draw()
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 9, in draw
    super(FigureCanvasTkAgg, self).draw()
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 388, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 38, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1702, in draw
    **self._tight_parameters)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 2476, in tight_layout
    pad=pad, h_pad=h_pad, w_pad=w_pad, rect=rect)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\tight_layout.py", line 362, in get_tight_layout_figure
    pad=pad, h_pad=h_pad, w_pad=w_pad)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\tight_layout.py", line 111, in auto_adjust_subplotpars
    tight_bbox_raw = union([ax.get_tightbbox(renderer) for ax in subplots
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\tight_layout.py", line 112, in <listcomp>
    if ax.get_visible()])
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 4355, in get_tightbbox
    bb_xaxis = self.xaxis.get_tightbbox(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1164, in get_tightbbox
    self._update_label_position(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 2014, in _update_label_position
    bboxes, bboxes2 = self._get_tick_boxes_siblings(renderer=renderer)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1999, in _get_tick_boxes_siblings
    tlb, tlb2 = axx.xaxis._get_tick_bboxes(ticks_to_draw, renderer)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1150, in _get_tick_bboxes
    for tick in ticks if tick.label1.get_visible()],
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1150, in <listcomp>
    for tick in ticks if tick.label1.get_visible()],
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 890, in get_window_extent
    bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 291, in _get_layout
    ismath="TeX" if self.get_usetex() else False)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 201, in get_text_width_height_descent
    s, fontsize, renderer=self)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 448, in get_text_width_height_descent
    dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 338, in make_dvi
    texfile], tex)
  File "C:\Users\haiqing\Anaconda3\envs\mie324\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 308, in _run_checked_subprocess
    'found'.format(command[0])) from exc
RuntimeError: Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found
```

Comment: Open a console / cmd prompt and type `latex`, Enter. Will you get a latex promt?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yes, and it starts with "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7140 64-bit)"

Comment: Anyways, for the people that tried to activate it and then could not use the notebooks anymore, I solved just removing the automatic use: matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = False

Answer (score 33):

When I tried to change the standard font for matplotlib, I likely incorrectly applied a recommended script and broke my matplotlib and from that moment on always got this error message.

Simply resetting matplotlib settings worked perfectly for me.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams.update(mpl.rcParamsDefault)
```

Comment: This works for me too. I was using lifetimes library in Python to plot survival function, and the same error was coming out. I committed pip install latex and it got installed but it did not solve my issue, this however did. I would say this is the perfect answer. BTW I am using Spyder IDE and Windows 10.

Answer (score 27):

I managed to solve this issue by installing [texlive](https://www.tug.org/texlive/) and [latex](https://pypi.org/project/latex/). In apt based Linux, this command installs texlive:

```
sudo apt install texlive texlive-latex-extra texlive-fonts-recommended dvipng
```

latex can be easily installed via pip:

```
pip install latex
```

Comment: This won't work anymore, because `cm-super` is missing. Fix it with `sudo apt install cm-super`.

Answer (score 16):

According to the `matplotlib` [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/text/usetex.html):

> Matplotlib's LaTeX support requires a working LaTeX installation, dvipng (which may be included with your LaTeX installation), and Ghostscript (GPL Ghostscript 9.0 or later is required). The executables for these external dependencies must all be located on your PATH.

If you're not familiar with `PATH`, this means that the `.exe` files of these programs need to be in your system environment variables. In Windows, *Edit the System Environment Variables*, click on variable *Path*, and add the filepaths of the aforementioned programs to the list.

- Get `LaTex` [here](http://www.tug.org/)
- Get `dvipng` [here](http://www.nongnu.org/dvipng/)
- Get `Ghostscript > 9.0` [here](https://ghostscript.com/)

Comment: What should be installed for OSX?

Comment: still not working for me... any idea? latex, dvipng, dvips work from the command line

Comment: Still does not work for OSX. I have latex (which latex works fine) I have installed dvipng, I have Ghostscript)...

Answer (score 9):

Matplotlib actually ships with its own way of doing TeX-style text, called [mathtex](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/mathtext.html):

> Note that you do not need to have TeX installed, since Matplotlib
> ships its own TeX expression parser, layout engine, and fonts. The
> layout engine is a fairly direct adaptation of the layout algorithms
> in Donald Knuth's TeX, so the quality is quite good (matplotlib also
> provides a usetex option for those who do want to call out to TeX to
> generate their text (see Text rendering With LaTeX).

In most cases, using this is sufficient and requires less stuff installed.

It's used in exactly the same way as LaTeX:

```
r'$\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_i$'
```

generates

[image: $\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_i$]

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, `MikTeX` doesn't seem to add it's `bin` folder to `PATH` during installation. Be sure to add:

**Local Install:**

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\
```

**System (Admin) Install:**

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\
```

to your `PATH` after installation. (Ironically, this gets removed from `PATH` when `MikTeX` is uninstalled). This should fix the problem.

**NOTE:** `%LOCALAPPDATA%` is `C:\Users\your-user-name\AppData\Local`.

Also, if you only need or want some text expressions rendered in `LaTeX`, and not the entire plot, `matplotlib` [uses a subset of `LaTeX` under the hood](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/mathtext.html#writing-mathematical-expressions) so you don't need to install `LaTeX` or set `rcParams` in that case.

e.g. On

**OS:** `Windows 10`
**Python:** `3.8.10`
**matplotlib:** `3.6.2`
**MikTeX:** `22.10-x64`
**Ghostscript:** `10.00.0`

notice the difference between the two:

#### Without `rcParams`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 100)
s = np.cos(4 * np.pi * t) + 2

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4), tight_layout=True)
ax.plot(t, s)

ax.set_xlabel(r'$\mathbf{time, t (s)}$')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$Velocity, v (\phi/sec)$', fontsize=16)
ax.set_title(r'Without rcParams', fontsize=16, color='r')

plt.show()
```

[image: Without rcParams]

#### With `rcParams`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.rcParams.update({
    'text.usetex': True,
    'font.family': 'serif',
})

t = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 100)
s = np.cos(4 * np.pi * t) + 2

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4), tight_layout=True)
ax.plot(t, s)

ax.set_xlabel(r'$\mathbf{time, t (s)}$')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$Velocity, v (\phi/sec)$', fontsize=16)
ax.set_title(r'With rcParams', fontsize=16, color='r')

plt.show()
```

[image: With rcParams]

It depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams.update(plt.rcParamsDefault)

this must be resolve the above issue, by putting the default paramater for the rcParams.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that the previous answers did not fix anything, you can use on this example and on scienceplots
`plt.style.use(['no-latex'])`