# Changing python matplolib plots to have Latex font

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do you get the font on plots to be Computer Modern Roman font?
Using commands like

```
mpl.rc('font', **{'family': 'serif', 'serif': ['Computer Modern']})
mpl.rc('text', usetex=True)
```

Just give me the error:

```
Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RuntimeError: Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58121461/runtimeerror-failed-to-process-string-with-tex-because-latex-could-not-be-found)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install LaTeX and ensure it works in your terminal first. See this: [RuntimeError: Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58121461/runtimeerror-failed-to-process-string-with-tex-because-latex-could-not-be-found)