# Python Matplotlib: How to bold a single character from a string with same font type

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there anyway I can bold a single character in python Matplotlib with same font type?

For example:  C**O**OH

The closest solution I found using python is:

```
plt.xlabel('C'+r'$\bf{O}$'+'OH')
```

However, the font type will become math Italian and is not the same with default font type

Answer (score 0):

You can do it activating latex.

```
from matplotlib import rc
rc('text', usetex=True)

plt.xlabel("C"+"$\textbf{O}$"+"OH")
```

I hope the font will stay the default type.

Comment: Thanks! I try this but the error appears, mention that latex could not be found... I guess I must install the Latex first?

Comment: You're welcome. Everything you need will probably be [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58121461/runtimeerror-failed-to-process-string-with-tex-because-latex-could-not-be-found). There is a few things (`dvipng`, `latex`, `Ghostscript`) to install if it is not already done.